# SocketException when trying to listen to multiple ports simultaneously C#

Tags: c#, sockets, http, ssl, networking

I'm writing a HTTP server and I would like to listen to *two* ports at the same time. 
I created two sockets and two `endPoint`s and I'm passing them to threads. 
I'm getting the following exception when the code is at `socket.Bind(endPoint);`:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

The code:

```
public class HTTPServer
{
    private readonly IPEndPoint m_LocalEndPoint=new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8082);;
    private readonly IPEndPoint m_SecuredLocalEndPoint=new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8083);
    private readonly Socket m_SocketListener=new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);;
    private readonly Socket m_SecureSocketListener=new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);; 

    public void Start()
        {

            Thread t = ThreadFactory.Create(() => AsyncStart(m_LocalEndPoint,m_SocketListener));
            t.Name = string.Format("HTTPServer({0})", this);
            t.Start();
            Thread sucureThread = ThreadFactory.Create(() => AsyncStart(m_SecuredLocalEndPoint,m_SecureSocketListener));
            sucureThread.Name = string.Format("HTTPSServer({0})", m_SecuredLocalEndPoint);
            sucureThread.Start();
        }


    private void AsyncStart(IPEndPoint endPoint, Socket socket)
        {
            try
            {
                socket.Bind(endPoint);
                socket.Listen(MAX_NUMBER_OF_PENDING_CONNECTIONS);
                Socket clientSocket = socket.Accept();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }          
        }
}
```

I don't know if it,ד relevant to the issue, but the reason I want to listen to two ports is that I want to be able to handle HTTP and HTTPS requests in the same server. 
So if a client sends a packet to port 8082 I will handle it as 
a HTTP request and if he sends to 8083 I will handle it as a HTTPS one. 
 What am I missing or how can I solve this problem (avoid the `SocketException`) and still listen to the two ports?

Comment: Is it possible that something else is listening on one of the ports you're trying to use? I've had this issue before when running a socket listener from within Visual Studio. My program had ended,but the thread was still active in the background occupying the port.

Comment: @Alex at the end of 'AsyncStart' method I have a 'finally' scope which inside I'm closing the two sockets.

Comment: It could be worth adding the finally scope to the code sample. Does this fail the first time you run it, or does it run correctly once with both sockets open, then fail subsequent times? Have you tried a port scan on your system to see if anything else is using the ports?

Comment: Ok, have you tried a port scan to see if there is anything else using the port?

Comment: @Alex You were right! There was another process listening to the same port. Please write an answer to the question so I could accept it :)

Comment: @ldos - Good stuff. I've lost count of the amount of times that has caught me out. I've lost hours debugging in the past when there was no issue with the code at all. Glad you have it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the socket is failing consistently on a particular port, it's likely that there is another process listening to the port.

Run a port scan on the local system to confirm the port is free.